# Writing UTF-8 chars in Textfield As3

Tags: actionscript-3, utf-8, localization, textfield

I have a textfiled (input type) which works with English lang. If I change to different locale in the system tray I am not able to write any text into the textfiled.

How can I enable this capabilty to the TextField or this is connected with locale/Language support in the swf?

Comment: do you use a special font in the textfield? maybe you have to embed it to be able to display foreign characters ...

Comment: Well I embed Arial. But tried also with my own font and the letters chaged, but I still cannot write when change the language support at system tray.  So the font thing works but only whe english is in system tray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flash IDE, there is an embed button under textfield properties. Open that window and add character range and add the special character that you want to exist to the "also include these characters:" field.

Comment: Yes I know this, but I work now in FlashDevelop and cannot use FLash IDE. How to embed language charatcers, for example cyrilic types of language supports?

Comment: you can use the EMBED meta-tag (http://mx.coldstorageonline.com/index.php?bid=48) and specify the `unicodeRange` attribute (optional, otherwise whole font will be embedded)

Comment: You can still use flash ide with flashdevelop btw, if you like to.

Comment: If I embed Hebrew font or some of the Arabian, will I be able to write from right to left?